# How to calculate the exponential equation in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to fit the exponential line to the points. It is working. But the linear formula appears in the diagram. I would appreciate someone telling me how to make the exponential formula in the plot.

```
Nu  treat   pH  Cd
1   Soil    6.1 0.28
2   Soil    6.1 0.29
3   Soil    6.1 0.28
4   Soil    6.1 0.28
5   Soil1   6.9 0.10
6   Soil1   6.6 0.16
7   Soil1   6.9 0.15
8   Soil1   6.6 0.11
9   Soil2   7.0 0.15
10  Soil2   7.1 0.13
11  Soil2   7.0 0.13
12  Soil2   7.2 0.13

my.formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x)
Pot=data[c(1:12),]

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=pH,y=Cd,col="treat"))+
  geom_point( size=4, data = Pot, shape=16)+labs(x="pH", y=expression(Cd~~~mg~(kg~soil)^{-1}))+
  geom_smooth(data = subset(data, Nu %in% c(1:12)),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x), method = "lm", se=F, level=0.95,size=0.5,linetype="dashed", col="black")+
  stat_poly_eq(data = subset(data, Nu=1:12),formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x),aes(label=paste( ..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep="~~~")),  
  label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = 0.1,  parse=T, size=6, col="black")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stat_poly_line` instead of `geom_smooth` like this:

```r
my.formula= y ~ exp(1.5*-x)
Pot=data[c(1:12),]

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=pH,y=Cd,col="treat"))+
  stat_poly_line(formula = my.formula) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,
               aes(label=paste( ..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep="~~~")),
               label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = 0.1, col = "black") +
  geom_point( size=4, shape=16)+
  labs(x="pH", y=expression(Cd~~~mg~(kg~soil)^{-1}))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It looks perfect! But on my computer has not been found the function  "stat_poly_line," even though I installed libraries ggplot and ggpmisc. Please write me what may be the issue here.

Comment: Hi @ShohnazarHazratqulov, Maybe you can try restart your R and Rstudio. `stat_poly_line` is from the `ggpmisc` package so it should work.